# Control multiple RPis from a master RPi

Tags: pi-3, networking, pi-3b+

I'm a newbie ;)

My Plan:
I want to have one "Master" RPi and have this one as an "center of home automation". The other Pis are going to be in differnet rooms and will be connected to the network via Wifi.
They shall have different functions (as booting pc, changing height of desk, a TV-wall if someone gets near by, and such things).
Till now I heard about ["MQTT (a good one for the Pi is Mosquitto)"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76030/controlling-multiple-pis-from-one-pi).
Does that fit my needs? And if so, do you guys know about good tutorials regarding this? 
(broad question, I know <3 )

Thanks!

---

edit:
found some mqtt tutorials with OpenHab - is that a reasonable path to go?

Comment: `is that a reasonable path to go` - yes

Comment: But keep in mind that using RPi just to boot your PC or change the height of the desk is really an overkill. Arduino would be a better choice IMO.

Comment: I’m currently searching for the balance, of what that desk shall be capable of. And what kind of infrastructure I’ll get.

Comment: 1) If i would like to go with one Pi as brain and Arduinos for the muscle, I would connect them using an esp8266 - right? 2) If so, the connection between Pi and Arduino will also be taken within Open hab, right?

Comment: There is more information needed to really point you the right way. If you just want to be able to "boot computer" or "move desk", why have the pi's networked? Just a webserver on them and you can go to that on your mobile phone and click the "button" that runs the script on the pi to action those things. I'd highly recommend you start with a tutorial like this one: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-05-27-internet-of-things-101-getting-started-w-raspberry-pi/

Comment: @Mark How is arduino a better choice for something for which a pi is overkill? I can get a pi zero for 5USD. Where can I find arduinos to match that?

Comment: @MatthewNajmon it's about the complexity of the system, not the price. In RPi you have whole Linux OS running, many things can go wrong, your SD card may fail, your program may crash etc. Pi is also not resistant to interference and it runs on 3.3V logic level. Arduino is actually Atmega microcontroller with bootloader and essential hardware on board. It's more reliable, sturdy, works with 5V logic. The point is - you don't need whole Linux stack running just to run the actuator. The simplier device that'll do the job, the better.

Comment: @Mark OK, that makes some sense. Still, for my projects, I'll stick with the most cost-effective that'll do the job. Simplicity is nice to have, but sometimes it's more expensive to get than it's worth.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon it depends if you include servicing, bugfixing and securing of the whole system in overall costs ;) Suddenly these few $ of difference doesn't matter that much. But hey, that's just my opinion! :)

Comment: Thx! Which place do you recommend to find the best fitting arduino? The number of variety... (There is the little plus for the RPi for beginners.) Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @Mark Arduino's setup is one I'd only ever be using for this sort of project. Linux is something I've spent most of the waking hours of my adult life using. I've worked on both, and found the Pi's programming, setup, bug-fixing, etc, to be much simpler intrinsically, but even if not, familiarity gap alone would mean such things further favor the Pi, not the Arduino. As for securing it, the only reason that'd even be a thing is the network connection, and Arduino loses that anyway, so connect Pi like you'd connect the Arduino (via not-ethernet), problem solved.

Comment: Or connect the Pis via ethernet, just on a LAN with no WAN connection or WIFI, depending on what interfacing options are desired (and any that require these will still require them with Arduino), problem still solved. How is that going to be any simpler on Arduino? Does Arduino even have off-the-shelf firewalls available?

Comment: Frankly, the ability of an attacker to potentially adjust the height of my desk really isn't operation-critical enough to warrant all that much in the way of security.